# Recursive permutations in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, permutation, infinite-loop

I'm trying to implement [Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm) for generating permutations. My code is below:

```
permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations [] = []
permutations (x:[]) = [[x]]
permutations xs = [ys ++ [xs !! i] | i <- [len,len-1..0], ys <- permutations (delete i xs)]
  where len = (length xs)
        delete i xs = take i xs ++ drop (succ i) xs
```

This is a direct translation from the [Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852004/596361):

```
def perms(A):
    if len(A)==1:
        yield A
    for i in xrange(len(A)-1,-1,-1):
        for B in perms(A[:i]+A[i+1:]):
            yield B+A[i:i+1]
```

Python code works, but Haskell code enters an infinite recursion. `permutations (delete i xs)` inside the list comprehension should bring the flow closer to base case. Why does infinite recursion happen?

**Edit:** [@augustss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649287/augustss) says:

> Always beware when you have multiple base cases for a function over lists.

So i changed the base case from

```
permutations [] = []
permutations (x:[]) = [[x]]
```

to more simple

```
permutations [] = [[]]
```

Comment: Also, your base case is wrong.

Comment: The permutations of an empty list should be `[[]]`.  If you add that you should not have to have a special case for `[x]`.  Always beware when you have multiple base cases for a function over lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loops aren't the same.

```
i <- [len,len-1..0]
```

vs

```
for i in xrange(len(A)-1,-1,-1):
```

The very first case, you're binding `i` to the length, not the length minus one. The result is that `delete i xs` returns `xs`, so you get infinite recursion.

I also have a couple of side notes.

First `!!` is linear-time. You'd be much better off writing a helper function that combines that `!!`, the `delete`, and the iteration over the input into one list traversal. Something like `select :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]`. You can do that efficiently.

Second, `++` is also linear time. Using it to append a single element to an existing list is slow. If your goal is just to produce all the permutations, rather than a specific ordering of them, you should probably use `(xs !! i) : ys` as the expression to return. (Suitably modified for any changes made in response to the first point.)

Answer (score 1):

#### `select`

Based on [@Carl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16966935/596361) I implemented `select :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]` function. It's task is to generate a list of tuples `(a, [a])`, where tuple's 1st part is an *element* from the list, and tuple's 2nd part is all elements from the list *except* that element.

```
select :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]
select [] = []
select (x:xs) = select' x [] xs
  where
    select' x left [] = [(x, left)]
    select' x left right@(r:rs) = (x, left++right) : select' r (x:left) rs
```

However I've found even simpler implementation of `select` on [Haskell Libraries mailing list](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2008-February/009270.html):

```
select :: [a] -> [(a,[a])]
select [] = []
select (x:xs) = (x,xs) : [(y,x:ys) | (y,ys) <- select xs]
```

Keep in mind that these 3 are equivalent ([`second`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:second) is a function from [`Control.Arrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html)):

```
[(y,x:ys) | (y,ys) <- select xs]
map (\(y,ys) -> (y,x:ys)) (select2 xs)
map (second (x:)) (select2 xs)
```

Here is the example of how to use `select`:

```
select [1,2,3] -- [(1,[2,3]),(2,[1,3]),(3,[2,1])]
```

Before I implemented `select`, I tried to find functions with type `[a] -> [(a, [a])]` in [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=[a]+-%3E+[%28a%2C+[a]%29]), there are several implementations in various libraries:

- as [`removeEach`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.11/docs/Data-List-HT.html#v:removeEach) from [`utility-ht`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.11) package
- as [`picks`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellForMaths-0.4.8/docs/Math-Core-Utils.html#v:picks) from [`HaskellForMaths`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellForMaths-0.4.8) package
- as [`parts'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmt-diagrams-0.15/docs/Music-Theory-Diagram-Path.html#v:parts-39-) from [`hmt-diagrams`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmt-diagrams-0.15) packages
- as [`extractEachElem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rosso-1.0/docs/Data-List-Rosso1.html#v:extractEachElem) from [`rosso`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rosso-1.0) package
- as [`extractElem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/spaceprobe-0.3.0/docs/Control-SpaceProbe-Internal-Probe.html#v:extractElem) from [`spaceprobe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/spaceprobe-0.3.0) package

#### `permutations`

The problem is, our `select` is not nearly enough to generate *all* permutations. We can cons both parts of each tuple using `uncurry (:)`, which has the type `(a, [a]) -> [a]`, but we only get some permutations, not all:

```
map (uncurry (:)) (select [1,2,3]) -- [[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,1]]
```

It's clear why, `select [1,2,3]` creates a list `[(1,[2,3]),(2,[1,3]),(3,[2,1])]`, but we must permute sublists, which are second parts of each tuple, too! In other words, if we have `(1, [2,3])`, we must add `(1, [3,2])` too.

The full code for finding all permutations of a list is below:

```
select :: [a] -> [(a,[a])]
select [] = []
select (x:xs) = (x,xs) : map (\(y,ys) -> (y,x:ys)) (select xs)

permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations [] = [[]]
permutations xs = [cons s2 | s <- select2 xs, s2 <- subpermutations s]
  where cons :: (a, [a]) -> [a]
        cons = uncurry (:)
        subpermutations :: (a, [a]) -> [(a, [a])]
        subpermutations (x,xs) = map (\e -> (x, e)) $ permutations xs
```

Note that the order of permutations of our function will be different from [`Data.List.permutations`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:permutations). Our function has lexicographic order, while `Data.List.permutations` hasn't:

```
permutations [1,2,3]           -- [[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[1,3,2],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
Data.List.permutations [1,2,3] -- [[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,1],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[1,3,2]]
```

Finally, if we simplify our `permutations` function even further, we get the implementation that is at [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#Haskell):

```
select :: [a] -> [(a,[a])]
select [] = []
select (x:xs) = (x,xs) : map (\(y,ys) -> (y,x:ys)) (select xs)

permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations [] = [[]]
permutations xs = [ y:zs | (y,ys) <- select xs, zs <- permutations ys]
```

Also note that Rosetta Code's implementation that uses insertion-based approach has the same (non-lexicographic) order as `Data.List.permutations`.

#### Notes

[FWIW](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for_what_it's_worth#English), there's a function [`scc :: [(a, [a])] -> [[a]]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uhc-util-0.1.6.0/docs/UHC-Util-Utils.html#v:scc) from package [`uhc-util`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uhc-util-0.1.6.0), which finds [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) of a Graph. First part of a tuple is a vertex, second part is all vertices, to which the edge from the vertex goes. [IOW](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_other_words#English), graph `1 --> 2 --> 3` becomes `[(1, [2]), (2, [3])]`.

```
scc [(1,[2,3,4]),(2,[1,3,4]),(3,[2,1,4]),(4,[3,2,1])] -- [[3,4], [1,2]]
```